# Adding more associations with foreign key

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, foreign-keys

I have two models: `Question` and `UserEdus`.

`UserEdus` can vote on `Question`.

After a vote, `Question` stores a list of associated `UserEdus`that voted. I am not sure how to create and add upon this association.

Is saying `Question` can have many `UserEdus` the correct way to think about this problem?

This is what I have so far.

```
class Question(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
content = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=False)
author = models.ForeignKey('UserEdus', null=False)
solution_found = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
points = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=False)
post_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)

class UserEdus(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
bio = models.TextField(max_length=400, help_text="Enter your bio details here.")
votes = models.ForeignKey(Question, null=True)
```

Upon hitting an upvote button this view is called,

```
def upvote(request,pk):
question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=pk)
question.points += 1
request.user.useredus.votes_set.add(question)
question.save()
```

This will return error `'UserEdus' object has no attribute 'votes_set'`

What am I doing wrong? The docs follow this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the related_name argument and a ManyToManyField model field. I would change:

```
votes = models.ForeignKey(Question, null=True)
```

To:

```
votes = models.ManyToManyField("Question", related_name="votes")
```

That way you can do a query like so:

```
somevar = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
all_votes = somevar.votes.all()
```

Your code would look like:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey('UserEdus', null=False)
    solution_found = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=False)
    post_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)

class UserEdus(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=400, help_text="Enter your bio details here.")
    votes = models.ManyToManyField(Question, related_name="votes")
```

Your upvoteview would look like:

```
def upvote(request,pk):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=pk)
    question.points += 1
    question.save()
    useredus = UserEdus.objects.get(user__username=request.user.username)
    useredus.votes.add(question)
    useredus.save()
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
request.user.useredus.votes = question
```

That's the correct way

Comment: I don't understand. UserEdus is a class and the foreign key is of class Question?

Comment: Did not work. The quotation marks are to set foreign keys to classes not yet defined.

Comment: request.user.Question.votes_set.add('a') replace with this and tell me what happen

Comment: 'User' object has no attribute 'Question'.

Comment: request.user.useredus.votes = question, that is the definitive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149343/discussion-between-michael-ninh-and-mauricio-cortazar).